# How to edit the specs content in pdp on electronic store provide by hybris?

Tags: e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud

I want to know from which cockpit you can edit the specs content that you see in product detail page of any product in the demo stores provided by hybris?

Comment: Are you looking for CMS Cockpit? http://localhost:9001/cmscockpit/login.zul

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- Manage product content (code,media, etc) at [http://yoursite/productcockpit/](http://localhost:9001/productcockpit/)
- Manage CMS Content (also PDP) at [http://yoursite/cmscockpit/](http://localhost:9001/cmscockpit/)